# Angular digest is not running when a promise is resolved

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, angularjs-digest

In my angular application I have a directive with isolated scope. The directive gets a string parameter in its scope and since this value might be initialized by the parent scope in an asynchronous process - it gets also a promise that's resolved by the parent when the value is ready to use.

Strange thing: when the promise is resolved the value in the directive's scope is still undefined, although in the parent controller it has a value.

See this plunker for an example of what I experience: 
https://plnkr.co/edit/WLILKaO95xWwU2RF29oX?p=preview

In the controller:

```
  $scope.defer = $q.defer();

  // to simulate an async operation
  $timeout(function(){
     $scope.ctrlValue = 'Hi';  
     $scope.defer.resolve();
  });
```

In the directive:

```
 scope.valuePromise.then(function(){      
     alert(scope.value);
 });
```

Important note: if I wrap the 'alert' line of code in a block of $timeout - the scope.value has the right value. It seems like angular is not running the digest when the promise is resolved.

Any ideas?

Comment: use `$apply()` for your timeout function

Comment: you have to either use $apply() or $digest() to initiate the angular digest cycle.. Without it the angular wont be able to know when to resolve the promise.

Comment: I know that $apply runs a digest, but I wanted to avoid this form some reasons - especially because it's throwing errors when there is another digest in progress. Is it really going like this - no digest after promise resolved???

Comment: I disagree with the other comments. To me, it's just a race condition: the promise is resolved and its callback function is called during the digest loop before angular "copies" the new value from the controller scope to the isolate scope. I wouldn't do it that way. Either resolve the promise with the new value (see https://plnkr.co/edit/Vcta2yfRE1DSB8WRZ67y?p=preview), or use a watcher (see https://plnkr.co/edit/h9SqAqtjeK0YhfzjChfi?p=preview)

Comment: Not at all. I will be happy if someone can help and answer. 
I do think that it's angular responsibility that the values should be up-to-date, that means promise's callbacks should not be called in the same digest where the promise is resolved.

Comment: You are right - timeout will solve the problem, but it feels like a workaround   rather than a solution. however - this is the only option I see now...

Answer (score 1):

Use `$timeout` in the directive. Some time is required to apply the changes of the parent scope to the directive scope. You tried to get the value while it was not updated.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, $q, $timeout) {
  $scope.defer = $q.defer();
  
  $timeout(function() {
    $scope.ctrlValue = 'Hi';
    $scope.defer.resolve();
  });
});

app.directive('dir', function($timeout){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      value: '=',
      valuePromise: '='    
    },
    link: function(scope) {
      scope.valuePromise.then(function() {
        $timeout(function() {
          alert(scope.value);        
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
    
    <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    
      <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
      <dir value="ctrlValue" value-promise="defer.promise"></dir>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: timeout is not a right option for getting data. It may take different time span based on the hits by users query performance may perform slow

Comment: @JinnaBalu That's what the topic starter used to emulate response from a remote resource.

Comment: This example is not that similar to mine - here the value is used in an expression, which is evaluated in every digest cycle, and that's why it is updated. in my case I need it to be updated immediately after resolve.